# Boris Red Compatibility issue warning on installing WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF desktop application. After i deploy the application and install the application in the system, I get a warning "This program has compatibility issues Boris Red v2.0".  You can get online and see more information about this program's compatibility issues. " I can continue with installation on selecting run the application without getting help. However, I don't know why I am getting this warning. I can see that Boris Red is part of Adobe and I am not using any Adobe features in my application. Is there a way i can prevent this warning.[image]

Also I noticed that the people who have Adobe Photoexpress and Adobe reader installed get this message.

Comment: What is `Boris RED`? Where is your code?

Comment: WPF or WinForms app? Those are two different kinds of apps just so you know.

Comment: @L.B I am not using anything related to Boris RED. Mine is a simple WPF desktop application. However, some people who have Photoshop express installed seems to get this message while installing the application. Not everyone gets it. I am not using anything related to photoshop or any other third party dll.

Answer (score 2):

It means you're installing versions of dll that those programs use.

Assuming you have the installation disks for the "incompatible" software you could experiment.

Often they are still compatible with newer versions of dll.

[Boris Red Compatibility issue warning on installing WPF application](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/4fbefe32-b805-4b06-89d6-c9fea5e78e48/boris-red-compatibility-issue-warning-on-installing-wpf-application?forum=wpf)